# Como validar un formulario con JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Estoy queriendo validar un formulario que esta dentro de un Modal de Boostrap con JQuery. El codigo esta desarrollado para que cuando en el input de id = "email", el value sea "roarias96@gmail.com", a ese input se le agrege un estilo Border Border-Danger de bootstrap.

Esto no estaria ocurriendo, ya que cuando ejecuto el boton de enviar, se envian los datos y el modal se me va.

Muchas gracias

```html
    <!-- VALIDACION DEL FORMULARIO DEL MODAL-->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnEnviar').click(function(){
            const email = $('#email').val();
            const pass = $('#password').val();
            
            if( email == "roarias96@gmail.com"){
                $('email').addClass('border border-danger')
            }
        });
    });
    </script>


    <!--MODAL-->
    <div class="modal fade md-6 border rounded" id="modelId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modelTitleId" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title text-justify">Iniciar Sesion</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container">
                        <form action="" id="formulario">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">@</div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group mt-4">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">@</div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnEnviar">Iniciar Sesion</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes cancelar el evento submit del formulario, para que no se envie,
ademas, me di cuenta que estabas llamando mal al campo email, te falto el #.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- VALIDACION DEL FORMULARIO DEL MODAL-->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#formulario').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            const email = $('#email').val();
            const pass = $('#password').val();
            
            if( email == "roarias96@gmail.com"){
                $('#email').addClass('border border-danger')
            }
        });
        
        $('#btnModal').on('click', function(){
          $('#modelId').modal('show');
        });
    });
    </script>


    <!--MODAL-->
    <div class="modal fade md-6 border rounded" id="modelId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modelTitleId" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title text-justify">Iniciar Sesion</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container">
                        <form action="" id="formulario">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">@</div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group mt-4">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">@</div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnEnviar">Iniciar Sesion</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnModal">Abrir Modal</button>
```

Comment: Ahi me funciono como deseaba, Muchas gracias

Comment: Marca la respuesta como correcta si te ayudó a solucionar tu problema.